# With CVAT, can we avoid storing images in docker container?

Tags: docker, cvat

Is it possible to set up CVAT do not storage the actual image files locally on the container?

I am trying to create a modular CVAT instance which can be easily deployed on various AWS instances. Right now, I am piping in a local storage folder into the docker for both the DB and CVAT (Django/data, django/keys, django/logs). It is working, but as we add more data to the project, the size of these folders is going to increase rapidly. Since we will be uploading from the same folders each time CVAT is deployed, is there a way to just work with the filenames and pull the images when needed vs. storing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of options, when [creating a task](https://openvinotoolkit.github.io/cvat/docs/manual/basics/creating_an_annotation_task/) import from:

- `Connected file share`, uncheck `Copy data into CVAT`, uncheck `Use zip chunks`, and check `Use cache`
- [cloud storage](https://openvinotoolkit.github.io/cvat/docs/manual/basics/attach-cloud-storage/) (use similar options to the fileshare)